# Replacing HTML footer content with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace my footer's text with "Hello World" and I do not want to edit the HTML by adding a class or an id

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
  </footer>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById(footer).innerHTML="Hello World";
```

The problem is that, when I do the code above, nothing is changing

Comment: Nothing happens? Wrong, an error message appears into the dev console, just take a look ...

Comment: Where did you declare the variable `footer`, and what does it contain? (Or did you perhaps mean a text literal in that place, instead of a variable?) Please go check your browser’s error console first of all … before asking.

Comment: @CBroe TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null[En savoir plus]

Comment: What - in code that doesn’t even use `document.querySelector` anywhere …? Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @ErikGesateifin Move  the script at the end of the body element.

Comment: @Teemu I can't edit the HTML, sorry.

Comment: Then execute the action after the page/DOM is loaded.

Comment: @Teemu Can you explain how to do that? Please

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`footer` is not the id of the element you are selecting, its the `tag` name.

You can use `tag` selector for selecting footer.

And to change the `div` content(i am assuming you want to change the text, keeping div as is), you can select div using the tag selector

and can change the text.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = "Hello World";
```

Above statement is broken down :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("footer") //select footer

document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0] //1st matched element

document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].getElementsByTagName("div") // select div

document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0] // first div

document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = "Hello World"; //change content
```

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = "Hello World";
```

```html
<footer>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are selecting id which doesn't exist, try this instead:

```
document.querySelector('footer').innerHTML = "Hello world";
```

@edit

```js
document.querySelector('footer').innerHTML = "Hello world";
```

```html
<footer>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: @ErikGesateifin hi, I updated my post with a code snippet, take a look at it, it might help you to replicate the solution

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways by which you can achieve the desired:

1) If you need to change the HTML, you should use the below code for targeting the `footer`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].innerHTML = '<div>Hello World</div>';
```

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].innerHTML = '<div>Hello World</div>';
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
</footer>
```

2) If you wish to just modify the text, without changing the HTML, you can also make use of the following:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].innerText = 'Hello World';
```

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].innerText = 'Hello World';
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
</footer>
```

> The difference between the two approaches is that the former keeps the text inside the `div` while the latter keeps inside `footer` tag itself.

If you look through inspection in the two, it will have an output like the below:

1)

```
<footer>
    <div>
        Hello World
    </div>
</footer>
```

2)

```
<footer>
    Hello World
</footer>
```